# How to limit vscode TypeScript IntelliSense options based on the object property value?

Tags: typescript, generics, intellisense, type-inference

I have an object with two properties: `type` and `position`. The `type` property can have a value of either 'a' or 'b'. The `position` property should be of type `"top" | "bottom"` if `type` is 'a', or `"left" | "right"` if `type` is 'b'.

```
type Height = { type: 'a'; position: 'top' | 'bottom' };
type Width = { type: 'b'; position: 'left' | 'right' };
type MyObject = Height | Width;

export const myObj: MyObject = {
  position: 'right',
  type: 'a',
};
```

The code itself is correct and will show an error if the value of `position` is not compatible with the value of `type`. However, when I try to access the `position` property on `myObj`, IntelliSense shows me all possible options for the `position` property, regardless of the value of the `type` property.

[image]

Is there a way to make sure that IntelliSense only shows options that are relevant to the `type` property? That is, when `type` is 'a', IntelliSense should only show options for `"top" | "bottom"`, and when `type` is 'b', IntelliSense should only show options for `"left" | "right"`.

Comment: Could you [edit] to make this a [mre] by reducing the code to [what's shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mZZ5em)?

Comment: This looks like a limitation of TS, but I can't find an existing issue in GitHub about it; you might want to file one yourself. Right now the only workaround I can think of is to make a helper function like, say, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdvDQW), but it's not great.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I was hoping not to use functions, but your solution looks very interesting. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: So, shall I write up an answer suggesting the workaround?  Or do you also want a canonical answer to "why is this happening" which would require someone to file a GitHub issue?

Comment: Yes, please write up the answer, it might be useful to someone else. I would also like to file an issue on github, but I'm not sure if this is a typescript or VSCode problem. Thanks

Comment: It’s TypeScript that provides the suggestion/completion list, so you’d want to file an issue with TS and not the IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug or a limitation in TypeScript's auto-suggestion list.  As you said, the compiler clearly knows which values are acceptable for `position` as soon as you specify `type`:

```
let myObj1: MyObject;
myObj1 = { type: 'a', position }
//                    ^^^^^^^^ 
// (property) position: "top" | "bottom"
```

But you get the union of all possible `position` values in your auto-suggestion list.

```
myObj1 = { type: 'a', position: "" }
// -----------------------------^
// : "bottom"
// : "left"
// : "right"
// : "top"
```

I was unable to find an existing [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about this; if someone files one, it should probably request that when entering a value of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type whose discriminant property has already been entered, the autocompletion/suggestion list for string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) should be filtered to just those applicable to the relevant union members.   And be prepared for the possibility of it being closed as a design limitation; it could turn out that fixing this would break desired behavior in other more common scenarios.

---

Anyway, until and unless this changes, I can only suggest workarounds.  One is to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function to narrow the input type by the discriminant so that the inapplicable string literal types aren't even available to the compiler:

```
const asMyObject = <K extends MyObject['type']>(
  obj: Extract<MyObject, { type: K }>
) => obj;
export const myObj: MyObject = asMyObject({
  type: 'b',
  position: '',
  // -------^
  // : "left"
  // : "right"
})
```

And if you're going to do that you might as well split them out into multiple arguments which might be easier for callers:

```
const asMyObject = <K extends MyObject['type']>(
  ...[type, position]: [
    type: K,
    position: Extract<MyObject, { type: K }>['position']
  ]) => ({ type, position });
  
export const myObj: MyObject =
  asMyObject('b', '');
  // --------------^
  // : "left"
  // : "right"
```

Neither way is wonderful, but it's at least possible to affect the suggestion list.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCWBzAFsKBeKBvKpIC4oByAQyIG4owB7AZ3mHmoDtCjhqwioAfYgI2rAOAW24BfcgFgAUHmgB1eABNgyDNlzgIbfhSp0GTVsQA2EAGbBufIgCckqCdLnaoAWRAB5fgCsIAMZomHCOaHxKqsgusuZoIt5+AIyEnj7+QS4A9FlQCelJGjjybGQANAb0jCxQ4rI5UI1NzS2tUAB6nV2dUPW5ABRgdpwQdqAAlJVGLIQARBxgs7xQs4LC1CKzsn35yUVaBMTlU9Ums0t1Mg0AtLd39w+PT3ftfVCAvBuA5Ltza6JbV7kvnNzFZ-g0gSsHChgGDAd8Vgt-tsZMwSCIILQwCQAtA4KZIHZClhZI0AixaGgSLQ0n5AsEoAAeADSUAgAA9gBBmMpaB5EhlgABtdjaIgAXQAfP0SU1qH5CABRDl2bHABk0gUVYraQgs8QSmWTdASqBy3wuRrsmhjKBk5gUvL81L8ukaKkaun9YkyZolAREMoyxo0KrGNhQpyBn1NG6PV7Rxrg+GzEEwoNQJNzCNp6PicayS6yO0O90uoIaZmsjlcnl89J04XycVSmUAOnbgvkFRD02YYsIgvTfqZUeaPdOiuVqvVZeAWoOOigeolwvHxnFMrFRpNXoX3cMp1q4xiMit1BtxfiTrrtPL6BlpfrQX6RD0FSIqaIx5lsee93jiZwsClg5oBHzJtmSIyLIQA)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer.